# How to list files in a directory with yield

Tags: python

The **iter** doesn't run. I just want to print out all words for each file in the directory /tmp.

```
class CorpusReader:
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname;

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname,fname)):
                yield line.split()

reader = CorpusReader("/tmp")
```

Comment: What do you mean by `__iter__` doesn't run?

Comment: Only "init" is running. The second function doesn't run.

Comment: The second function shouldn't be running. What the second function does is it allows an instance of CorpusReader to be iterable. So if you do `for i in reader:`, it will be iterable.

Comment: `for f in reader: print f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to loop through `reader`:

```
for line in reader:
    print line
```

## Update

Keep in mind that not all files are readable, you need to guard against this case:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            try:
                for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname,fname)):
                    yield line.split()
            except IOError:
                pass  # or handle this error, most likely due to file not readable
```

Answer (score 1):

The second function, `__iter__`, allows an object of the class `CorpusReader` to be iterable. This means that you can iterate over it in a for loop (or other iterable methods). To print all the files do this

```
for i in reader:
    print(i)
```